# Problems executing onEdit() trigger when another script edit the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

I have created an GUI app that allows a user to submit data and writes the data in a Spreadsheet. This Spreadsheet has the visibility option: "anyone with the link" and "Can edit" permission.

Also, there is a onEdit() trigger that should be executed everytime that a change has been made. There is no problem to write the data to the Spreadsheet but the trigger is not working.

Could you please assist me in this matter?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

onEdit trigger is executed only when you manually change the contents of the table.

You can create general function and call it from UiApp and execute onEdit:

```
function edit(str){ //general onedit function
  //do somethig (For example add " edited")

  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell(); 
  cell.setValue(str + ' edited');
}

function onEdit(){
  var str = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  edit(str);
}

function gui(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var tb = app.createTextBox().setName('tb');

  var hndlr = app.createServerHandler('onSend').addCallbackElement(tb);
  var btn = app.createButton('Send').addClickHandler(hndlr);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app.add(tb).add(btn));
}

function onSend(e){
  var str = e.parameter.tb;
  edit(str);
}
```

*sorry for my bad english =)*